# How to convert Echo message from php to string for comparison?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want to convert an echo message received from webserver into a String which i would like to compare with another string in **onPostExecute**
 method.
When enter the correct values only the else part of **onPostExecute** is displayed. Why so? What should i do to fix this?

```
@Override
public String doInBackground(String... params) {

    //String reg_url="http://127.0.0.1//webapp/Register.php";
        String reg_url="http://10.0.2.2/webapp/Register.php";
        String login_url="http://10.0.2.2/webapp/login.php";
        String method= params[0];
        if(method.equals("register"))
        {
            String name=params[1];
            String u_address=params[2];
            String user_pass=params[3];
            String u_email=params[4];
            String u_zip=params[5];
            String u_mob=params[6];

            try {
                URL url = new URL(reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("user","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("address","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(u_address,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_pass,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("emailid","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(u_email,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("zip","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(u_zip,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("mob","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(u_mob,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                os.close();
               BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));

                String result;
                result = bufferedReader.readLine();
               // / InputStream is= httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
               // is.close();
               // return "Registration Success...";
                return result.toString();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }
            /*catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/
        }

    else {
            if (method.equals("login")) {
                String login_name = params[1];
                String login_pass = params[2];
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(login_url);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
                    String data = URLEncoder.encode("login_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                            URLEncoder.encode("login_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_pass,"UTF-8");

                    bufferedWriter.write(data);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    os.close();

                    InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                    String response="";
                    String line="";
                    while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                        response+=line;
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                    return response.toString();

                }
               /* catch(Exception e)
                {
                    return null;
                } */
                catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    return null;
}
```

I am trying to compare echo response returned from server which in turn returns to onPostExecute method as shown below

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
   /* if(result.equals("Registration Success...")){
        Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
    //if(result.equals("Login Success...")){
        //  Toast.makeText(ctx,"Login Success!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
    /*else
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx,"Failed!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } */

   /* if(method.equals("login"))
    { */
    loading.dismiss();
        if(s.equals("Login Success..."))
        {

            Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,MainActivity.class);
          //  intent.putExtra("USER_NAME",login_name);
            ctx.startActivity(intent);

        }


   /*     else{
            Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    else if(method.equals("register")) {
   */
        else if (s.equals("Registered Successfully")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,Login.class);
            ctx.startActivity(intent);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(ctx,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
   // }
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen from a server i am sendng the PHP echo  message as "Login Success" or "Login Failure"  which i want to compare in onPostExecute method. If it equals with response message then Intent must execute

Comment: Always the else part of onPostExecute is displayed.. Why so? and what should i do to fix this @SverriM.Olsen

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the echo message is in the code above.
I'd advice to create a string variable and equate it to the echo message. Like:

String serverResponseText = new String(serveResponse.toString());

That should fix your problem. Goodluck

Comment: I want to check whether response from doInBackground equals "Login success.." or not. If it equals then it should move to a new Activity> But every time the else part is executed. I want to know why?

Comment: If the response string isn't the same as what you're checking it with, it might not give you the result you need. Simply call the onPostExecute method from within doInBackground method using an if else. You can also use the compareTo() method.  Can you show the code passed to the server from your view file or what you're using